# When is Assisted-inject useful?

Tags: java, guice, assisted-inject

I'm currently using `Guice` in my App. However I find myself mostly using assisted inject because there is a chain of injected objects that all depend on what was the input of the program.
Hence almost everything is assisted inject.

For instance A need B who need C who need Z which needs input from the command line. In the end I feel like everything will be assisted injected. So given that I'm stuck with it I want to be sure that I'm using it right.

I personally feel like writing my own factories would be as good. Moreover, in addition to the same advantage I could further limit the creation of my objects in question to these factories.

Hence my question here is, how useful is it really to use assisted inject, is it only the idea of having things assisted and non assisted as the same time? What if like in my case you have only have assisted parameters?

Their must be some gain at organizing it with assisted injection. I just don't see it.

PS:

My dependency is as such:

I have an **InfrastructureService**, which require a **KnowledgeBaseService** which in turn require an **ConFigDataObject**. My configDataObject contains information coming from the inputs of the program. *The configDataObject store these information after doing some validation and processing on those inputs*. For instance a string representing file path can be provided to it, and it will validate that it is file that exist, and have a getter method that return that File to its consumer. Other things might be URLNname to real URL Object, and so on.

The important point here is this following graph:  **InfrastructureService** -> **KnowledgeBaseService** -> **ConFigDataObject** -> **InputData**

Therefore the **InfrastructureService** can only work with a **knowledgeBaseService** that is started with the right inputFile, URL, workingfolder and etc.... which is provided to it with a configDataObject, that receive them from the input of the program and store a processed version of them.

Therefore as of now what I do is to have a assistedFactory to create the **knowledgeBaseService**. It takes as parameter the ConfigDataObject. The **configDataObject** is created with a *factoryMethod (Scala Companion Object)*. Finally, the an assistedFactory is also create for the **InfrastructureService** which takes as parameter for its *creation method* a **KnowledgeBaseService**.

As you can guess everything is pretty much created upfront, and somehow manually. I find it odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i did to finally solve the issue in a more elegant way than using an unnecessary chain of assisted injected due to the parameters of the application.

that is If as in my case your data comes from the command Line then the right appraoch i believe is to bind the type of the input data structure to instance input structure obtained from the command line:

```
object MyApp extends App {

  val config = ConfigData(args(0))

  val injector = Guice.createInjector(module(config))
  val service = injector.getInstance(classOf[InfrastructureService])

  println("The service name is:" + service.kbService.config.configName)

}


case class module(config: ConfigData) extends AbstractModule {
  def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[ConfigData]).toInstance(config)
  }
}

case class ConfigData(val configName: String)

class KbService @Inject() (val config: ConfigData)

class InfrastructureService @Inject() (val kbService: KbService)
```

I believe the Key here is to remind yourself that the module can be parameterize with any input data deem necessary

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that you are overusing a notion of "dependency". You should separate classes which encapsulate user input (in fact, any data) from classes containing business logic first, and then you should pass these data via methods, not through injection, because user input is not a dependency.

This way you will almost never need assisted injection, because you can create "data" classes directly with `new` (it is OK because they have no dependencies), and "behavior" classes can be injected into each other via constructor in standard way. Then "behavior" classes will do they work, passing around objects of "data" classes, not getting them as dependencies. You will see that the need for assisted inject disappears, and your program becomes much more simple and understandable.

For example, instead of having something like the following:

```
public class OtherDependency {
    private final int s;

    @Inject
    OtherDependency(@Assisted int s, ...) {
        this.s = s;
        ...
    }

    public void doWork() { /* use s */ ... }
}

public class SumService {
    private final int x1;
    private final int x2;
    private final OtherDependencyFactory depFactory;

    @Inject
    SumService(@Assisted int x1, @Assisted int x2, OtherDependencyFactory depFactory) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.depFactory = depFactory;
    }

    public void doWork() {
        int s = x1 + x2;

        OtherDependency dep = depFactory.create(s);
        dep.doWork();
    }
}

public class EntryPoint {
    private final SumServiceFactory sumServiceFactory;

    @Inject
    EntryPoint(SumServiceFactory sumServiceFactory) {
        this.sumServiceFactory = sumServiceFactory;
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x1 = sc.nextInt();
        int x2 = sc.nextInt();

        SumService sumService = sumServiceFactory.create(x1, x2);
        sumService.doWork();
    }
}
```

(I don't know much about your program, obviously, but this is what I have thought of when I have seen "chain of dependencies which need user input first")

you should make something like

```
public class OtherDependency {
    @Inject
    OtherDependency(...) {
        ...
    }

    public void doWork(int s) { /* use s */ ... }
}

public class SumService {
    private final OtherDependency dep;

    @Inject
    SumService(OtherDependency dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public void doWork(int x1, int x2) {
        int s = x1 + x2;
        dep.doWork(s);
    }
}

public class EntryPoint {
    private final SumService sumService;

    @Inject
    EntryPoint(SumService sumService) {
        this.sumService = sumService;
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x1 = sc.nextInt();
        int x2 = sc.nextInt();

        sumService.doWork(x1, x2);
    }
}
```

All user input is transferred from class to class via method parameters, and these classes themselves are stateless and are just normally injected. No need to use assisted inject at all.

**Update**

I have read your update. There are multiple possibilities to do what you want, with varying complexity.

First, one of the most simple variants (and I'd argue the best one in these circumstances) is, again, to pass your input data via method calls. I do not see how your architecture forbids this. Just make all methods on `KnowledgeBaseService` which need this data accept it, and pass it from `InfrastructureService`. You do not need assisted inject here.

Second, you can acquire your user input before creating an injector, and then do `toInstance()` bind. This depends on the actual architecture and may not work because of it. I believe this is the easiest approach which give very simple and flexible structure.

Third, you can use providers. Create a provider for your `ConfigDataObject` which asks for user input and creates corresponding instance, then bind `ConfigDataObject` to it in `Singleton` scope. This will work if user input does not fail, because you should not throw exceptions from providers. If you need user input validation, use [throwing providers](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders) extension. User input will then be triggered upon the first access to the provider, and then due to its scope the result will be cached.

There may be other ways, but these are which I was able to come up with.

Comment: Many thanks, for your answer, i have update the my question with some example, to clarify my case

Comment: Good answer.  If you have configuration data that can't change over the life of your application, another possibility is to bind that data object with Guice as well.  If it changes with every request (for example), you could make it `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: Tavian, Could you clarify your first point. I don't think my case fall into the answer of Vladimir. My case do not involve injecting factories for instance. Everything comes at the beginning of the program not inside several service. So in a sense it is simpler. I believe your first point(i.e. "to bind that data object with Guice as well") match my problem. However i'm not sure how.Could you develop on that please

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. I believe i would lean toward the second solution. The first solution is simply not viable. The data in config data are used once to initialized the The KbService. It contain a triple store and a DL Reasoner that needs those info to get initialized.

Comment: I was wondering, what do you think about binding constant instead. In fact what i did is to create a class that old all the properties necessary to initialized my application. Maybe the best way is pass only what is necessary and therefore bind to constant. Wouldn't it be the best practice ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon, It depends. When you have many parameters, you'll have to create many binding annotations, which can be inconvenient to use, or you could use `@Named` annotation, but it means using unchecked strings as identifiers. However, if there are not too many parameters, constant bindings are perfectly fine.